# Laravel converts integer to NULL when returning Model as JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-5.6

This is the weirdest mistake I've ever seen in my life, I don't know how to explain it, but it's happening.

When returning a list of models from the controller:

```
public function index()
{
     return MyModel::orderBy('name')->get();
}
```

I'm getting the following feedback in the browser:
[image: return with error]

Now if I switch to:

```
public function index()
{
     return MyModel::orderBy('name')->get()->toArray();
}
```

I get the following feedback in the browser:

[image: expected return]

After trying to find a solution so that I don't need to call the `toArray()` function, I found that by overriding the `jsonSerialize()` method as in the example below, in the `MyModel` class, it correctly converts the `cost_id` to a number.

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return parent::jsonSerialize();
}
```

If I put the field as string in the `$casts`, it works, but converts the numbers to string.

My Model:

[image]

My backend:

- PHP 5.6.40
- Laravel 5.4
- Database is DBMaker

Comment: Is there any reason for your case to NOT set a default value of `0` instead of leaving it `NULL` and causing unpredictable behaviour?

Comment: If there is any reason to come NULL, I don't know. In no time do I try to manually convert this value.

Answer (score 0):

The cost id should not be fillable, this is your primary key and most likely set to auto increment, it also should not be casted because primary key should be an integer which auto increments

However should you still wish to follow this design and have cost_id being fillable then

1 - make sure its either an integer or a string
2 - don't case it if you don't need to
3 - possibly, in your controller try normal response such as `response()->json(MyModel::orderBy('name')->get());`

I don't guarantee above will work for you as it does seem strange bug, have you checked your database and ensured that cost_id for this specific record is ok? as in is is integer and not a string? is it not null?

Let me know how it goes

Also a side note:

I would suggest having normal ID field which is a primary key and auto increments

Comment: I'm not trying to create a record, I'm just trying to return all records as JSON. About the database, see that all other records correctly come as an integer, only the first q doesn't. But, you're right, I accidentally put it in the fillable